# Is there an Orange server to deploy the models developed in Orange 3

Tags: orange

I am new to Orange 3 and while the tool looks very promising, I was wondering if there is an Orange server where the model can be deployed for a production instance.

Answer (score 1):

No. Orange is a stand-alone, desktop application and is not a tool for designing analysis pipelines that would on their own run on the servers. Instead, it fosters interactive visualizations and exploratory data analysis that all require human input.